# Getting previous/next row node in a sorted grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have a grid with a default sorted on a column and I'm having problems getting the next/previous rows by adding or substracting from the currently selected row ID.

Here's the column with the default sort

```
{
  headerName: "Created",
  field: "createdOn",
  cellRenderer: (params) => {
    return WebModule.Utils.dateFormat(params.value);
  },
  sort: "desc",
  width: 125
},
```

And here's my logic to get previous/next row

```
class ResultModal {

    constructor(params) {
        this.params = params
        let rowIndex = params.rowIndex;
        this.previousRow = params.api.getRowNode(rowIndex - 1);
        this.nextRow = params.api.getRowNode(rowIndex + 1);
        this.result = params.data;
    }
}
```

I pass the whole ag-grid params object to a modal so I can navigate the grid records from buttons in the modal.

The issue is that if I run the above logic with the 2nd row selected, `params.rowIndex` is 1, I get `nextRow` with (1+1) but the actual `rowIndex` of `nextRow` will be something like 2245 (I have lots of data in the grid).

So I end up selecting a row burried deep down in the grid instead of the actual 3rd row displayed.

Do I need to use something else than `getRowNode` when the grid is sorted/filtered ?

Comment: I hope ag-grid lets you distinguish between visible and non-visible rows when your data is filtered (letting you skip past the hidden rows) -- but if not, could you just use a Map or Array to manually track the ids of the visible rows, then look at the next item in your Array to get the next visible row's id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using `api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex()`

```
let node = params.api.getSelectedNodes()[0];
let rowIndex = node.rowIndex;
this.previousRow = params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(rowIndex - 1);
this.nextRow = params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(rowIndex + 1);
```

This really gets the previous and next row regardless of the sort/filter options.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution might be to use

**gridOptions.api.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort**

which iterates over the rows as they are displayed. Note that the callback passes the RowNode itself and the row-index in the grid.

```
function forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort(
    callback: (rowNode: RowNode, index: number) => void
): void;
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-rowNodes